# unable to remove an unsuccessful (abandoned) gem in rails, which causes the bundler update to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have recently started to learn rails and had a lot of trouble installing the mysql2 gem. Finally gave managed to install the mysql gem and abandoned mysql2. I have just created my first app, which failed to a great a GEMFILE.lock. I SO'd this and ran the bundler update cmd.

It returned the following issue:

extconf failed, exit code 1 (same issue that prevented me from installing the mysql2 gem)
...
Make sure that 'gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'' succeeds before bundling

I then delete: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2

However, I run bundler update again and the gem returns, producing the same error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah I have found the solution.

What I did was change the 'mysql2' in my GEMFILE to 'mysql' (the gem I am using for MySql-Ruby), which did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Delete mysql2 from the Gemfile, add the mysql, then `bundle install`. Should work.

And overall, in Rails pretty much everything you want to do with gems will be by using bundler, not by installing single gems.